# Edit action error (First argument in form cannot contain nil)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this Rails app, Users can write Stories and add them to Collections. As they write a Story, users can add it to an existing Collection or create a new one while in the stories/new.html.erb view through a modal.

I have this working for the New action, but the Edit action is broken. It throws an error that says 
**First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty** on this line

```
  <%= form_for [@user, @collection] do |f| %>
```

My code looks like this

stories_controller.rb

```
  def new
    @story = Story.new
    authorize @story
    @user = current_user
    @collection = Collection.new
  end

  def edit
    @story = Story.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
```

stories/edit.html.erb loading a _form.html.erb partial

```
 <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for [@user, @collection] do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :description %>
          <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control collection-desc-input-box", placeholder: "Give it a description (this is optional)" %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-lakeside" %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

routes.rb nested resource

```
  resources :users do
    resources :collections
```

**EDIT:**

Fixed the problem by putting Collection.new in the edit action. Would be good if someone can explain what's happening. I fixed this by trial and error. Thanks.

```
  def edit
    @story = Story.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @user = current_user
    @collection = Collection.new
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize/set `@user` and `@collection` in your edit action, they are nil and so the error. Since they are initialised for `new` action, it is working.

You can do something like the following for `@user` and `@collection` can be initialised in their respective actions accordingly:

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:new, :edit]

private

def set_user
  @user = current_user
end
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. In other actions and views I am able to call current_user but here it just refuses to work.

Comment: are you logged in? I doubt, if you are using devise then put `before_action :authenticate_user` to verify user login. Mostly the user is logged out.

Comment: managed to fix the problem but I don't know how I did it. solution is in the edit above. if you can help me understand what's going on that would be great, thanks!!

Comment: that's what I was asking you to do, `initialize @user and @collection` and that's what you did.

Comment: in your console, you can check this, when you type `user` or any random string like `asdfgh`, it will throw error of uninitialised variable or method, but when you make it instance variable like `@user` or `@asdfgh` it will return nil and no exception is raised. As a result, when you were passing `@user` and `@collection` to form, since they were not initialised, their values were `nil` and form doesn't accept nil values. As you have set them in controller it is working

Answer (score 0):

You missed `@user` and `@collection` instance variable in store controller.

Try below code:

```
#stories_controller.rb

  def new
    @story = Story.new
    authorize @story
    @user = current_user
    @collection = Collection.new
  end

  def edit
    @story = Story.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
  end
```

Comment: managed to fix the problem but I don't know how I did it. solution is in the edit above. if you can help me understand what's going on that would be great, thanks!!